# Escaping characters in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Say I want to escape characters in org-mode, e.g. `_` so that org-mode renders the following:

```
* _TARGET_
```

In my set up (which I think is the default one) org-mode underlines the word as opposed to rendering `_TARGET_`

More generally, where can I find information about how to escape characters in Emacs org-mode?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [code and verbatim](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Emphasis-and-Monospace) markup will render the text inside as-is, without interpretation. Therefore, `=_TARGET_=` will probably work as you intend (you'll also get a different monospace typeface for that word).

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be great for single lines. Do you know if there is a way to have a full block (i.e. multiple lines) in verbatim?

Comment: #+begin_example ... #+end_example should give a verbatim block

Comment: Of course, it would be great if we didn't need to change font just to escape a character.

Comment: Any idea, how would you escape a = now? for eg. if I have a section like 

"use == and != as comparision operators"

Answer (score 9):

With a current Emacs and org-mode you might try

```
* \under{}TARGET\under{}
```

If that is not automagically displayed as `* _TARGET_` just try `C-c C-x \`, that should toggle the display of those codings between coding characters and coded character.

(In principle the same as I explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443386/how-to-escape-double-quote/31207746#31207746).)

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, use the normal shell backslash to escape the characters you want to avoid Org-mode interpreting as markup:

```
* \_TARGET\_
```

The backslash characters are visible in your Emacs buffer, but are hidden when exporting - e.g. to HTML or PDF-via-LaTeX.

This escaping works in many other situations, e.g. `SR\_1234` to render as `SR_1234` during export rather than as a subscript.

Comment: @jake -- you're right. No longer works for me for 8.2.10 either. Something must have changed in the intervening years...!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to break org to interpret some syntax you are using, you will have to ways to do that.

1. Using escape char. `_` is `\under` and `*` is `\ast`, so you can write like this `\ast \under{}TARGET\under`;
2. Another way is to use [`zero width space`](https://orgmode.org/manual/Escape-Character.html), its code is `200B`, so you can use `C-x 8 RET 200b RET` to insert a zero width space to break the interpreting.

They work on the latest org on the responding time (latest 9.2).