# How to escape double quote?

Tags: emacs, markup, org-mode

In org mode, if I want to format text a monospace verbatim, i.e. `~...~`, if it is inside quotes: `~"..."~`, it is not formatted (left as is).

Also, are quotes a reserved symbol, if so, what do they mean? (they don't seem to affect the generated HTML / inside Emacs display).

Comment: Changing something inside verbatim, isn't that a contradiction?

Answer (score 8):

The culprit in this case is the regular expression in <strike>`org-emph-re`</strike> `org-verbatim-re`, responsible for determining if a sequence of characters in the document is to be set verbatim or not.

> org-verbatim-re is a variable defined in `org.el'.
>   Its value is
>   "\([     ('\"{]\|^\)\(\([=~]\)\([^
>   \n,\"']\|[^
>   \n,\"'].*?\(?:\n.*?\)\{0,1\}[^
>   \n,\"']\)\3\)\([-     .,:!?;'\")}\]\|$\)"

quotes and double quotes are explicitly forbidden inside verbatim characters `=~` by

```
[^ 
\n,\"']\|[^ 
\n,\"']
```

I found discussions dating back 3 years comming to the conclusion that you have to tinker with this regular expression and set the variable `org-emph-re`/`org-verbatim-re` to something that matches your wishes in your emacs setup (maybe a file local variable works as well). You can experiment by excluding double quotes from the excluding character classes and outside matches as in

> "\([     ('{]\|^\)\(\([*/_=~+]\)\([^
>   \n,']\|[^
>   \n,'].*?\(?:\n.*?\)\{0,1\}[^
>   \n,']\)\3\)\([-   .,:!?;')}\]\|$\)"

but looking at that regex, heaven knows what happens to complex documents -- you have to try...

**Edit**: as it happens, if I evalute the following as region, quotes inside `=` are exported correctly, but nothing else is :-), I investigate further when I have more time.

> (setq org-emph-re "\([ ('{]\|^\)\(\([*/_=~+]\)\([^ 
>   \n,']\|[^ 
>   \n,'].?\(?:\n.?\)\{0,1\}[^ 
>   \n,']\)\3\)\([- .,:!?;')}]\|$\)")

**Edit 2:**: Got it to work by changing `org.el` directly:

Change the line following `(defvar org-emphasis-regexp-components` from `'(" \t('\"{" "- \t.,:!?;'\")}\\" " \t\r\n,\"'" "." 1)` to `'(" \t('{" "- \t.,:!?;')}\\" " \t\r\n,'" "." 1)` and recompile org then restart emacs.

This was a `defcustom` prior to the 8.0 release, it isn't anymore, so you have to live with this manual modification.

regards,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I found a solution from http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/82571

According to that thread, the regexp for verbatim is built from variable `org-emphasis-regexp-components`, which defines legal characters before, after, at the border of, or in the body of emphasis; and verbatim is one of the emphasis environment in org mode.

A workable setting given by that thread:

```
(setcar (nthcdr 2 org-emphasis-regexp-components) " \t\n,")
(custom-set-variables `(org-emphasis-alist ',org-emphasis-alist))
```

Answer (score 2):

I've met similar problem, and thanks @chaiko for a basic solution. However, @chaiko's solution only work for org-mode's fontification, it doesn't affect `org-export`. To get correct exported document, you need to do some more extra hack to org-mode's parser by `(org-element--set-regexps)`.

So the full code snippets should be something like:

```
(setcar (nthcdr 2 org-emphasis-regexp-components) " \t\n\r")
(custom-set-variables `(org-emphasis-alist ',org-emphasis-alist))
(org-element--set-regexps)
```

I've integrated this to my oh-my-emacs project: https://github.com/xiaohanyu/oh-my-emacs/blob/e82fce10d47f7256df6d39e32ca288d0ec97a764/core/ome-org.org#code-block-fontification .

Answer (score 2):

For small amounts of characters which have some unwanted effect in Emacs org-mode (because being metacharacters) it may be helpful to have a look at [special symbols](http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-symbols.html) in org-mode ([org-entities.el](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-entities.el;hb=HEAD)).

So for example `"` can be encoded by `\quot{}` (where the braces pair at the end is not mandatory, but needed if no whitespace follows).

So instead `="..."=` you would write `=\quot{}...\quot{}=`.

That is some typing more and looks pretty ugly. But for the latter org-mode has a solution: by `C-c C-x \` you can toggle a display magic for those symbols. If the magic is active, so directly after typing `\quot{}` resp. `\quot{}` a `"` will be displayed.

Besides, this symbols list can easily be extended, f.e.

```
(add-to-list 'org-entities
'("backslash" "\\textbackslash" nil "\\" "\\" "\\" "\\"))
```

Nevertheless I am heavily missing easier escaping in org-mode, besides the above solution and besides escaping a whole line by a `:` at its beginning.

I'd be happy if `=verbatim=` in all cases would leave the text between the `=`'s unchanged. Not `=this`**`*bold*`**`text=`, but `=this *bold* text=`. Like we know that from each well-designed markup/-down language.

But, of course, this is better placed at the org-mode development pages. Ideally with a fitting patch...  :-)