# How to decorate a string that starts/ends with ' or " in emacs org mode

Tags: emacs

In Emacs org mode,
we can use `*bold*`, `/italic/`, `_underlined_`, `=code=` and
`~verbatim~` to decorate our text in line.

However, I found that if the string to be decorated starts or ends with `'` or `"`,
the decorating characters will not work any more.

For example, `=echo "Hello, world!"=` can not be exported as `<code>echo "Hello, world!"</code>`,
but as `=echo "Hello, world!"=` instead.
`/'dog'/` can not be interpreted as *italic*, but as normal text.

How to solve this problem? any advice?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443386 not exactly a duplicate, because I don't think that the issue has been fully resolved, yet it will help you out, if you want to know the reason for it being this way.