# How can I emphasize or verbatim quote a comma in org mode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I tried to make the comma `*,*` bold, but no success. I tried with verbatim `=,=`, but no success as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by adding the following to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setcar (nthcdr 2 org-emphasis-regexp-components) " \t\r\n\"'")
(org-set-emph-re 'org-emphasis-regexp-components org-emphasis-regexp-components)
```

#### Explanation

The [manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Emphasis-and-monospace.html) says that `org-emphasis-regexp-components` can be used to

> fine tune what characters are allowed before and after the markup characters [...].

It is a list containing five entries. The third entry lists characters that are *not* allowed to immediately follow or precede markup characters. By default, `,` is one of them so in order to successfully apply formatting to this character we have to remove it from the list of characters disallowed before or after the markup characters. This is what the call to `setcar` does. The purpose of the second line is to rebuild the regular expression for emphasis based on the modified version of `org-emphasis-regexp-components`.

---

#### Sources

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23600071/1199226) to a related question
- [`~"~` doesn't register as verbatim](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/82571) on the `org-mode` mailing list
- <kbd>C-h v</kbd> `org-emphasis-regexp-components` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

There's a similar problem and I've figured out a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443386/how-to-escape-double-quote/30911948#30911948).

@itsjeyd's solution is right but not 100% correct. We need an extra `(org-element--set-regexps)`.

The full code snippets:

```
(setcar (nthcdr 2 org-emphasis-regexp-components) " \t\n\r")
(custom-set-variables `(org-emphasis-alist ',org-emphasis-alist))
(org-element--set-regexps)
```

Comment: Yes, @itsjeyd's solution should be amended. Your answer is perfect. Also, one needs to make sure to have `(org-mode)`, or else `(org-element--set-regexps)` will not work. Thank you.

Comment: @itsjeyd's solution worked for me on OSX 10.11.6 /  Emacs: 25.1.1 / Spacemacs: 0.105.21. This worked too but raised an error.