# orgmode: inlining verbatim material

Tags: org-mode, verbatim

I use verbatim mode to inline code and simple expressions. The problem I have is that some tags cause the verbatim mode not to be recognized. When I type `=(a b)=` I see `(a b)` look right, but when I type `='(a b)=` the [lisp] quote tag somehow negates the verbatim mode, so I get ='(a b)= in text style. What can I do to remedy this, so I can get `'(a b)`

Comment: Here's a workaround: It is possible to insert a special character: a "zero width space", which is 0x200b in UTF8, between the left = and the quote mark. This character has no visual consequence, but allows orgmode verbatim to expand correctly. To insert this character, type C-x 8 <ret> 200b <ret>

Comment: The solution in your comment worked for me.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate of [How can I emphasize or verbatim quote a comma in org mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24169333/1199226). The accepted answer to that question tells you what you need to do :)

Comment: @MayerGoldberg Sounds like an answer to me. It's not *great*, but it works and would allow this question to pop off the unanswered list. The only way this can get truly fixed is if it's considered a bug in org and the regular expressions are changed.